# Passing OAuth id token from html page to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm using OAuth google sign-in in my web-project and I have logged in successfully using OAuth sign-in in HTML page now i want to check if the user is signed in (i.e)if he is not signed-in then he should not access other pages of my project like, for normal java login with password we use filter concept as if he  is not logged in it redirects to the login page . how can I do the same thing(filter concept) using OAuth in my web-project using HTML and servlet . and I also don't know how to pass the id_token of the user login in OAuth to the servlet as I'm a beginner in this stuff.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is that i created a hidden input (eg) in html along with in OAuth sigin button and when signed-in I,changed the value of that hidden  to name of the user logged in by **getElementById.value**  then in servlet i got the user name using **getParameter** and made a session and if the session values is null then redirect to the login page else the page work , hence the user cannot access the other pages of your webapplication without sigin.